# read matrix from file using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am new in python. I want to read a multiple array from text file to a python array

```
[
    [
        [1 1] [1 1]
    ]
    [
        [2 2] [2 2]
    ]
    [
        [3 3] [3 3]
    ]
    ...
    ...
    ...
]
```

I have tried this but seems I am not really good with python

```
dt = np.dtype(None, 2, 2)
data = np.fromfile(fileName, dtype=dt)
print(data)
```

by the `np.dtype` I want to tell python that the type is an array of unknown size containing arrays that each contains two arrays of two integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read printed numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914697/read-printed-numpy-array)

Comment: it's about converting a string to an array, and how can I read data from file to a variable?

Comment: You can get it as a string with `open(fileName).read()`.