# reading np array from a text file

Tags: python

i have this array in a text file:

```
[[0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 4, 4,],
 [1, 0, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3,],
 [4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 0,]]
```

my code is written with python and i want to read it and use it as a np-array in my code, how can i do that.

Comment: Do you have control over the generation of that file? In other words, can you change its format?

Comment: @ash Wrong, `loadtxt` cannot handle brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the formatting; you can clean that up with regex and then simply load the whole array with np.loadtxt(). Assuming your file is called 'array.txt':

```
import numpy as np
import re
with open('array.txt','r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
nums = re.findall(r'\[([^][]+)\]', txt)
arr = np.loadtxt(nums)
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to extract runs of numbers without square brackets, then split each run, and convert each substring into a number:

```
import re
runs = re.findall(r'\[([^][]+)\]', data)
np.array([[float(n) for n in run.split()] 
          for run in runs])
#array([[0., 1., 3., 1., 3., 3., 1., 5., 2., 4., 4.],
#       [1., 0., 4., 1., 3., 1., 1., 3., 2., 2., 3.],
#       [4., 3., 1., 3., 4., 5., 2., 5., 4., 5., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution I've seen elsewhere ([Read printed numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914697/read-printed-numpy-array))

```
import re 
import numpy as np  
from ast import literal_eval

dat = """[[0. 1. 3. 1. 3. 3. 1. 5. 2. 4. 4.]  
          [1. 0. 4. 1. 3. 1. 1. 3. 2. 2. 3.]
          [4. 3. 1. 3. 4. 5. 2. 5. 4. 5. 0.]]"""   
a = re.sub('\s+', ',', dat) 
a = np.array(literal_eval(a))
```

output:

```
 array([[0., 1., 3., 1., 3., 3., 1., 5., 2., 4., 4.],
        [1., 0., 4., 1., 3., 1., 1., 3., 2., 2., 3.],
        [4., 3., 1., 3., 4., 5., 2., 5., 4., 5., 0.]])
```