# Printing and reading Numpy arrays efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to print a Numpy array and then read it back. This is what I have done so far:

```
#printer
import numpy as np

N = 100
x = np.arange(N)
for xi in x:
    print(xi)

#reader
import numpy as np

N = 100
x = np.empty(N)
for i in range(N):
    x[i] = float(input())
```

This gets the job done but I think that it may not be the most
efficient way due to the multiple uses of `input()`. An alternative way I considered is printing only once, reading only once and modifying what I read. This approach has some similarities with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914697/read-printed-numpy-array). In contrast to that question, I have some extra info that could possibly be used to improve performance:

- N is known in advance(to both programs)
- Arrays are only 1D or 2D(of sizes N and NxN respectively)
- Data are float
- Data are fully trusted

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have to add that the value of `N` will not be that large, even `N=1000` will be huge for my problem.

Comment: Well an optimization would be to print the entire array `x` only once. Regarding the reading part, I think it is fine. In the end, the `input` is dynamically run so you are not adding any extra time on the code itself.

Comment: @DavidDuran Printing once and reading the way I do now gives the following value error: "Could not convert string to float" which is kinda expected. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: No, I was meaning to print the entire array. To read it, I would still use the second loop.

Comment: That's what gives the error. After printing the entire array once, input sees only a string of the form "[0 1 2 3]" which cannot be converted into a float.

Comment: It is strange... I cannot reproduce the error. I just replaced the first loop for `print(x)` (deleting also the second import, which is not necessary) and the input is working to me...

Comment: I see where the misunderstanding is. The second import is necessary because it's actually two separated programs. If you want to reproduce the error, I suggest you to run the reader program with a small value of N, copy the output and then run the second program and paste.

Comment: Look at using the `np.savetxt` and `np.genfromtxt` pair, if you want a text file.  Or `np.save` and `np.load` if it doesn't have to be text.  The `print/str` display of a `ndarray` is not designed for loading.

Comment: @hpaulj I gave them a look. They seemed like useful tools so thanks for pointing them out. Unfortunately, I don't think I can use them now, at least not without major changes to my code. The problem is that printer and reader run simultaneously so if I use a file instead of printing, I can't be sure that that the printer has printed all data before the reader tries to read it. Perhaps there will also be an issue with two programs trying to open the same file at the same time.